# Cannot pass arguments in dispatcher.invoke

Tags: c#, vb.net, invoke

I will need to convert the following **VB Form** code to **WPF C#**:

```
// VB
Me.Invoke(New FooDelegate(AddressOf Foo), New Object() {cmd})
```

Where `Foo` is just a method taking a string argument `cmd`.

I tried all the following in WPF C#, but all giving me exception:

```
//C#
dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo()), cmd);
dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo(cmd)), cmd); 
dispatcher.Invoke(new FooDelegate(Foo()), new object() {cmd});
```

What is the correct formatting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling function with `()` instead of geting its address. Unless ProcessCommandCT returns function it should be something like:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(new ProcessCommandDelegate(ProcessCommandCT), cmd);
```